# Can't adjust special permissions - Unable to contact Active Directory to access or verify claim types

Tags: windows, permissions, active-directory

This is an AD domain environment. I want to update a user's "Special Permissions" on a folder.

The advanced permissions are however grey. I see the error at the bottom "Unable to contact Active Directory to access or verify claim types"

[image]

What is preventing me from editing the advanced permissions for this user on this folder? When I view the parent folder - the user which has special permissions on the parent, the advacned permissions are fully editable.

The user I am adjusting, I am logged in as that user now and this user is the owner of both the parent and the new subfolder that I am trying to edit the advanced permissions on.

Comment: Shouldn't you be solving first why the user is cut off from the domain?

Comment: @harrymc The user logged in tho, via Kerberos... so theyre not cut off? Also the system is not unjoined or else the shares wouldn't work without entering password?

Comment: Is your DC set as your primary DNS server?

Comment: @harrymc Yes yes